# How to save Instance State of LinkedList<String> in recyclerView, so it does not destroy on rotating device?

Tags: java, android

I've got an app that uses `RecyclerView` which is made by Google's codelabs. When a `TtextView` item from a `LinkedList<String>` is tapped it changes to "Clicked + attribute value", but on rotating my device the activity destroyed and it shows only "attribute value. Also on tapping FAB icon, it adds a new word in `LinkedList<string>` which also cleared when rotating the device. My question is, how can I save the `insatance` state of my app that activity does not get destroyed on rotation.

Here's the link to the project: [https://github.com/JoblessJoker/RecyclerView]

Comment: activity has the corresponding callbacks to save and restore states. Use them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special method provided by android framework to allow you to save the state

```
onSaveInstanceState()
```

Inside this method, you can save the state of the list. One way would be to save it inside the bundle given as a parameter.

You will then receive the same bundle in your onCreate and onCreateView methods where you can use them to get the previously saved data.

Alternative approach is to save the data in a persisting storage like SharedPreferences or Database in the onPause() and then fetching this data in onResume() or whenever you want.

All these approaches are valid and all are good, the approach you choose depends on you

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out){
   out.putString("test","test");
   super.onSaveInstanceState(out);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
   if(savedInstance!=null){
     //We have saved state
     String test = savedInstance.getString("test");
   }else{
     //We do not have saved state, get the data from intent extra or argument for fragment
     String test = getIntent().getStringExtra("test");
   }
}
```

You can save the data relevant to you in this way

Comment: Can you please provide the code by using onSaveInstanceState() method?

Comment: there you go, it's a very simple case but i hope it will guide you